# How do I add an edited open-source project to my own project?

Tags: angular, github, npm

I have downloaded an open-source package from github and I've made the edits that I needed to make it work in my own project.

Now, I need to place the edited code into my own project. How do I do this? The project is in Angular 4 and I'm using npm.

I am very new to using npm and Angular so I've mostly just done npm installs of packages I would need. How do I make sure I'm getting my edited version and not the original version from github?

Answer (score 0):

You should put up a fork/repository of your changes on Github (or any other git versioning system), which also makes them easier to track.

If you have your repository up on Github or anywhere else, you can simply use

`npm install <git remote url>`

to install your package!